# Getting only decoded payload from JWT in python

Tags: python, jwt

Is there a nice way (using maybe some library) to get only payload from JWT saved as string variable?
Other than manually parsing it for content between first and second dots and then decoding.

Comment: make your choice: https://jwt.io/#libraries-io

Comment: Man that's what i'm struggling with. All these libraries provide comprehensive approach. All that I want is to get easily a nice body of payload just like jwt.io allows me to do after pastying JWT into their tool.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The library [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation) has an option to [decode a JWT without verification](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation):

Without this option, the `decode` function does not only decode the token but also verifies the signature and you would have to provide the matching key. And that's of course the recommended way. 
But if you, for whatever reason, just want to decode the payload, set the option `verify_signature`to false.

```py
import jwt
key='super-secret'
payload={"id":"1","email":"myemail@gmail.com" }
token = jwt.encode(payload, key)
print (token)
decoded = jwt.decode(token, options={"verify_signature": False}) # works in PyJWT >= v2.0
print (decoded)
print (decoded["email"])
```

For PyJWT < v2.0 use:

```
decoded = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)  # works in PyJWT < v2.0
```

It returns a dictionary so that you can access every value individually:

> b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im15ZW1haWxAZ21haWwuY29tIn0.ljEqGNGyR36s21NkSf3nv_II-Ed6fNv_xZL6EdbqPvw'
>
> {'id': '1', 'email': 'myemail@gmail.com'}
>
> myemail@gmail.com

Note: there are other [JWT libs for python](https://jwt.io/#libraries-io) as well and this might also be possible with other libs.

Comment: What if I want to have the header as well?

Comment: this is how it's done: jwt.get_unverified_header(token)

Answer (score 4):

I used it today and seems like it needs the algorithm used too:

```
token = jwt.encode(payload, key=JWT_SECRET, algorithm="HS512")

jwt.decode(token, algorithms='HS512', verify=True, key=JWT_SECRET)
{'id': '1', 'email': 'myemail@gmail.com'}
```