# How to decode a JWT token without a secret using Python

Tags: python, jwt, decode

When I go to https://jwt.io/ I'm able to decode my token without any secret. I just paste the token and it'll be decoded.

But when I go to my code and try to decode it without a secret, I'll get the following error:

```
jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
```

This is my code:

```
import jwt

token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoidGhpcyBpcyBhIHNlY3JldCBtZXNzYWdlIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc4MjE1ODY1fQ.jrNYdkoNau5H20CGXlHK5nASGxY7xLD8LF6zxt-thLY'

decoded = jwt.decode(token, verify_signature=False, algorithms=['HS256'])

print(decoded)
```

By the way, this like will work just fine

```
decoded = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', verify_signature=False, algorithms=['HS256'])
```

And this will also fail

```
decoded = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', verify=False, algorithms=['HS256'])
```

Is there a way to decode it without the secret like in https://jwt.io?

Comment: What do you think happens if you ignore the _validation_ part of the JWT process, and just assume that whatever the user happened to put in the payload is the truth?

Comment: Did you try `jwt.decode( token, options={'verify_signature': False} )`, as the documentation suggests?

Comment: You can split a JWT by `.`, take the second part, the payload, and decode it with base64url. But doing this means that the JWT can be modified by the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting only decoded payload from JWT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425161/getting-only-decoded-payload-from-jwt-in-python)

Answer (score -2):

Try passing these all three parameters to jwt.decode as shown below. It worked for me.

```
import jwt

token = <YourToken>
decoded_token=jwt.decode(token,algorithms=['HS256'],options={'verify_signature':False})
```

Comment: That basically just repeats the answer of the proposed duplicate target. The algorithms paramter is meaningless if you don't verify the signature.