# Python jwt decode returning Could not deserialize key data error

Tags: python, jwt

I have a jwt token generated from aws cognito which gets authenticated in aws api gateway and successfully calls my aws lambda behind the gateway. Everything works and this is a valid jwt received in my aws lambda python, but I'm unable to parse this valid JWT in my python code. Below is the snippet of python method where I pass in the auth header:

```py
def decodeJWT(authHeader):
   jwt_token=authHeader.replace('Bearer ','')
   print(jwt_token)
   decoded_jwt=jwt.decode(jwt=jwt_token, algorithms="RS256")
   return decoded_jwt
```

The value of authHeader passed is below. I've validated the "Bearer " string is removed, and the remaining jwt is valid. This jwt also gets decoded correctly on the site "jwt.io", and seems to be a valid jwt since it gets decoded, and also the auth works on gateway.

`Bearer eyJraWQiOiJmUjFiZ21VdzhoNW9RUnZxeVUwZW9jbkhsSU1CbTNZMHRGS3oyVXFLNjVzPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.BKdUHR_al5IAprfZHK9fEC7kthrv6kpyDXdsM6nrUQufVEMliIyz1dk3ruGhDDP4HjW8czlwegoYDX5aqrou3AkXWivsN8JplJELwb3li9XsHOrBhajLgHYwTUdEm5EFQcyxTD22IvkeByHokvzeOW1IakHIR_qdiH4zv9MNfjpy2svuS7imnnik1XLGx0A7eZmq6IDQlfu3v1Bk_ePBpgaOlZBEypmcIaZe5BySbZo6QrLfzASgwfMF0XrJYwtydgq3jz7L3EWEO1IaHT3x-qwZuOC8S4n3m0hr-PZwt7r3akXb75OlFbJMoWRuuWViC-Jpqzm3e72ueNc5BeSIBQ`

Below is the error I receive:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 350, in prepare_key
    RSAPrivateKey, load_pem_private_key(key_bytes, password=None)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 25, in load_pem_private_key
    return ossl.load_pem_private_key(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 747, in load_pem_private_key
    return self._load_key(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 929, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 984, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])
```

---

Python 3.11.2; pip 23.3.1

Comment: In your call `jwt.decode(...` you didn't pass any key. That's probably the problem. If you just want to decode the token without verification, you need to set `"verify_signature": False` in the options as shown in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425161/getting-only-decoded-payload-from-jwt-in-python).

Comment: Thank you, I only had to decode without token verification. This solution works!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting only decoded payload from JWT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425161/getting-only-decoded-payload-from-jwt-in-python)